# Redirect two links from old domain to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect only 2 links from old domain to new domain not all links from old domain
example :

```
https://old-domain.com/profile/teams  to  https://new-domain.com
```

and

```
https://old-domain.com/activities  to  https://new-domain.com
```

only this this two links

I did

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase https://old-domain.com/profile/teams
RewriteRule (.*) https://new-domain.com [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase https://old-domain.com/activities
RewriteRule (.*) https://new-domain.com [R=301,L]
```

but I get 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule on site root .htaccess of old domain:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(profile/teams|activities)/?$ https://new-domain.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

Regular expression `^(profile/teams|activities)/?$` matches `/(profile/teams` or `/activities` followed by an optional trailing slash.

Comment: isn't redirect at all

Comment: sorry for late answer. Yes my .htaccess is accessible and exist

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: when I put some uncorrect stuff I get 500 error page